# App Transport Security has blocked Parse files... Swift 2 error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, ios9

I continually get this type of error in my app which uses a Parse.com backend:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

I have tried adding the following to my info.plist but it has not worked. No other solutions online have worked. Does anyone know what to do?

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>files.parsetfss.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionsAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: have you tried only with the key `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads=true`? I mean, without specifying the exception domains

Comment: @dGambit Yes, I tried just `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>` This did not work.

Answer (score 6):

This plist entry is working for me -

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>files.parsetfss.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludeSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

You have the key `NSIncludesSubdomains` rather than `NSIncludeSubdomains` - an extra s between 'Include' and 'Subdomains'

Comment: Hmm. I changed it to this, and that didn't seem to work. Still getting an error, and it is not downloading the picture I want.

Comment: Hmm.  It is working for me and if I change the domain I get the ATS error message.  Are you sure that the info.plist you are editing is the one that your app is using?

Comment: Use the domain files.parse.com

Answer (score 0):

Also Parse just announced that they will update their SSL certs to be ATS compatible...

Comment: "Tuesday, August 11, 2015" was the day they were supposed to update. It's still not working...?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just add above plist entry in your projects Info.plist

Comment: Use any REST client and run it on your machine. call the webservice and ensure that your machine would be able to connect with your webserver.

Comment: This is a Bad Idea (tm) as it will make all connections vulnerable. See this answer for for the right solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32560433/1103584